# THIS java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ERROR

Tags: java, error-handling, compiler-errors

```
public static int StringInString(String one, String two) {
        if(one==null||two==null||one.equals("")||two.equals("")){
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            int x=one.length(),y=two.length(),sum=0,i=0,j=0;
            char[] onee=one.toCharArray();
            char[] twoo=two.toCharArray();
            while(i<x){
                while(j<y){
                    if(onee[i]==twoo[j]){
                        i++;
                        j++;
                    }
                    else{
                        if(j==0){
                            i++;
                        }
                        else{
                            j=0; 
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                sum++;
                i=i-y+1;
                j=0;
            }
         return sum;
        }
    }
  public static void main(String[] args){
    int sum;
    sum = StringInString("salamsal","sal");
    System.out.println(sum);

 }
```

hello I dont know why this ERROR apear?! please HELP me;
this code want count the similar text in two stringsa
and the result of this code should be = 2.

Comment: Debugging should point you in right direction instead of posting the code here.

Comment: tank you for your attention and help

Comment: Do you need to do it this way? There is a much easier way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are inside the second "while" cycle, even if i > x, the cycle continues as long as j < y. So when it happens that i++ in the second cycle makes i become greater than x-1, and j is still less than y, in the first "if" (always inside the second while cycle) the program tests if onee[8] == twoo[0], and since onee[8] doesn't exist (because the indexes of "salamsal" go from 0 to 7) it shows the error that the index is out of the array bounds. To solve the error you should check for the value of i inside the second cycle, because it may happen that i++ makes this index become greater than x-1, where x is, as you declared, the length of the first string.